# writing groovy code for CLI commands in build.gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In Android Studio, inside my `build.gradle`, can I write a task which includes groovy code for CLI commands? I want to my commands to execute only by executing the tasks and not running them every time through CLI. Like I have a command I am executing through CLI:

```
gradlew <task_name> -Dorg.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.hardcoded = true
```

In the above command, I am writing a task to clone a repository from bitbucket and passing my credentials in CLI as I execute the command. Is there a way I can write this inside my task?

Comment: Didn't get a chance to try, Will try in some time . thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`System.setProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) anywhere in gradle script.
So you can just add at the beginning of the script:

```
System.setProperty('org.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.hardcoded', 'true')
```

or more groovier:

```
System.properties['org.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.hardcoded'] = true
```

But it would be better to put it in the task directly:

```
task someTask << {
   System.properties['org.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.hardcoded'] = true
}
```

When the task is finished it's good idea to clear the property with [`System.clearProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#clearProperty-java.lang.String-).